# mysql - filter results by excluding results greater and lesser than

Tags: mysql, sql

My DBA primary and secondary are MIA and I don't have time to learn SQL (or MySQL). Hoping someone can help me out. Please and thank you in advance.

I need to edit a query to filter out specific results.

For example, the query will output into a file 3 columns: first_name, last_name, hours_worked.

For column 3, I need to filter out anything less than 30 and greater than 100. I tried using:

where hours_worked>100 or hours_worked<30

Unfortunately that seems to break the query as the text file generated is empty.

Comment: The where clause will *include* only rows with hours_worked over 100 or less than 30.  Based on the specification, to "filter out" those rows, it seems like we'd want... `WHERE hours_worked BETWEEN 30 AND 100 OR hours_worked IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

The where clause specifies conditions that a row must fulfill in order to be part of the result (and not the oposite, i.e. filtered out).

So the condition should be `where hours_worked >= 30 and hours_worked <= 100`.